# M8000 lever blade fit a m785 lever?

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, brakes

I bent my lever blade on a m785 lever and was wondering if a m8000 lever blade would fit as I can find one of them but not a m785 lever blade. The reason im asking is because the m785 blade says "B" fit m8000 but the m8000 blade doesn't say that for m785 so Im wondering if they're the same lever blade. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A "B" fit means that the part is interchangeable but the finish, graphics or potentially the shaping of non cantact parts is different.

It *will* fit.